# Approve this mac using another device

Tags: macos, icloud, security

I bought a new MacBook Pro (macOS Sierra v10.12.4), and I'm having some issues with iCloud. Even tho I never had a Mac before, I did run on my VMWare a MacOS (I don't recall using the iCloud back then).

Whenever I try to log in to the iCloud, it asks for my Apple ID and MacBook Pro passwords. after that, I get this message:
[image: iCloud security code form]

When I click the **Forgot Code?** button, I get an alert that says:

> If you can't remember the iCloud Security code, you can approve this Mac using another device.
>   **Cancel** | **Use Other Device**

When I click on the **Use Other Device** button, the alert gets closed and then nothing happens. I've tried running iCloud on my PC to get by any chance there the code, but unfortunately, no luck.

Any solutions?

Comment: Looks like you have 2-Factor Authentication turned on.  Can you log into icloud.com and turn it off?

Comment: @fsb I can login to icloud.com. Although, I don't see 2-Factor Authentication in there.

Comment: Looks like you need to change it from a different site.  See if this info helps: http://osxdaily.com/2016/08/17/disable-two-factor-authentication-apple-id/

Comment: did you end up figuring it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have an iPhone or iPad? If yes, then one of these can be used to receive the code. A PC won't work as I know.

If you still don't receive the code on your iDevices, try the following on your iPhone or iPad:

1. Go to **Settings** > ***Your Name*** (Apple ID, iCloud, iTunes & App Store) > **Password & Security**.
2. Enter your Apple ID password when asked.
3. Tap **Get Verification Code**

This might only work with Keychain enabled on your iDevice.

If you don't have any other Apple devices, it could be your last option to reset the iCloud Keychain. But in this case I'd prefer to call the official Apple Support.

Comment: Ok. TBH not the answer I hoped for, but looks like I should call them after all. Thanks.

Comment: Okay so you're telling me anyone who doesn't have iphone or ipad can't use an apple desktop normally. So if we want to use the expensive apple desktop we have to also buy an expensive iphone or ipad. That is the most draconian thing I have ever heard in my life.